# Xamarin in Visual Studio packaging failed | mono-symbolicate error -1073740791

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, packaging

I'm getting the following error when trying to packaging my Xamarin Android application. The application works perfectly in debug mode on my mobile, now I'm just trying to generate the APK and I get this error message:

```
Archiving App Bundle 'PoolHeatingClient'...
Creating archive directory 'PoolHeatingClient'...
Creating directory 'C:\Users\entro\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives\2016-10-29\PoolHeatingClient 10-29-16 4.21 PM.apkarchive'...
Deleting files '*.apk'...
Packaging 'PoolHeatingClient'...

The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mono-symbolicate" store-symbols "bin\Release\PoolHeatingClient.PoolHeatingClient.apk.mSYM" "obj\Release\android/assets"" exited with code -1073740791.


Failed to create App archive 'PoolHeatingClient'.
```

I don't know where to start from...
Thanks,
Michele

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{43716C55-E6A1-4F1D-8E2E-947AD36C37E3}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>PoolHeatingClient</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>PoolHeatingClient</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AndroidApplication>true</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v7.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>True</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <BundleAssemblies>False</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <Debugger>Xamarin</Debugger>
    <AotAssemblies>False</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>False</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>False</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <EnableProguard>False</EnableProguard>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <BundleAssemblies>False</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <Debugger>Xamarin</Debugger>
    <AotAssemblies>False</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>False</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>False</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <EnableProguard>False</EnableProguard>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="GettingStarted.Xamarin" />
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Main.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\Strings.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-ldpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xxhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xxxhdpi\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
     Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
        <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        </Target>
        <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        </Target>
 -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Does the project build in `Release` mode? Can you double check that you all your `assets` have the correct `Build Action`?

Comment: Yes it builds in Release mode and it works on my mobile.Can you explain the second sentence a bit more? My Assets folder is almost empty, only AboutAssets.txt is there (I guess it's a default readme file...).

Comment: Can you upload a copy of your `.csproj` or paste the contents to your question? It looks like another user is running into this here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46164 I would suspect there is a setting enabled that shouldn't be.

Comment: It is done! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I mean, it is uploaded... I still need help :D

Comment: Assuming you turn `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` to false, does the project package in `Release`?

Comment: Hi Jon, I tried but it doesn't work either. Could it be the fact that I'm using a Google Drive location? Sometimes I am obliged to close google drive to be able to access the file (which are on my PC physically...).

Comment: That's definitely possible. Try to move a copy locally to `C` or close on the `C` drive.

Comment: I just tried, same result :(

Comment: Looks like we are digging into this issue here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46164 If you have a small project that you can upload to help us reproduce, please feel free to add it to the bugzilla and we'll get this sorted out ASAP!

Comment: Yes my project is very small but... I don't know why the project folder is 176mb! I only have an icon in PNG format with multiple size and that's all!

Comment: Delete your `bin` and `obj` folders and it should clear up a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I've uploaded it :)
Feel free to comment any mistake, it's my first project!

Comment: Can you try using the `Beta` channel as per my observation here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46164#c9

Comment: Great, it works like charm!
Thanks a lot Jon and Ooi!

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this is a bug in the current Stable build. There is a reported bug on this issue here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46164

However based on my observations, you can solve this issue by directly updating to the Beta channel via:

`Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Switch to Beta -> Check for Updates`

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46164#c9

I've also added a workaround here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46164#c14

Which you will need to add the following to your `Release` configuration in the current Stable build:

`<AndroidManagedSymbols>False</AndroidManagedSymbols>`

Comment: To those who are not sure where to add this xml configuration, there is a <AndroidManagedSymbols>True</AndroidManagedSymbols> part in your .csproj file. This needs to be set to False.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and the latest beta (4.2.1.15) suggested in the comment solved this issue.
To get the beta version. Go to Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Xamarin > Others > Change from Stable to Beta > Check Now