# Can't Archive Xamarin Android app to get a apk | mono-symbolicate error -1073740791

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-assembly

I've made an android app with xamarin. I can build it in release mode without problems. But when I try to archive it, it always shows me this error:

```
The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mono-symbolicate" store-symbols
 "bin\Release\FIRMNAME.Zukunftstag.FIRMNAME.Zukunftstag.apk.mSYM"
"obj\Release\android/assets"" exited with code -1073740791.
    Build FAILED.
```

[Pastebin because it's pretty long](http://pastebin.com/Pu9k7uD4)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40363313/1048571

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin in Visual Studio packaging failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320084/xamarin-in-visual-studio-packaging-failed)